nftables does not catch a packet it has already seen
I setup a segmented local network, where each segment is VLAN'ed and the switch at the root of all VLANs also acts as router between all IP segments/VLAN (the switch is the Dell S4810 Running DNOS 9.14)
On of the segment holds the gateway to internet, and the Internet gateway's local IP address is the S4810's default gateway IP address. Before forwarding packets to the outside, it applies SNAT (masquerade) so that the packet forwarded towards Internet has the default router's public address as source address. Nothing fancy here. Almost everything seems to work as expected: a node in either segment can contact other nodes in other segments, they can all reach internet and get a reply, and nodes outside this LAN do see the correct, masqueraded source IP address.
Things gets tricky when the Internet gateway machine (NOT the S4810) also runs VMs with Proxmox. This machine runs Debian 12.5 and is configured with VLAN interfaces on top of the physical one going to the S4810, and the VLAN interfaces themselves are wrapped into bridges, one per VLAN. The interface towards internet is also wrapped in its own bridge. I use bridges so that Proxmox VM can use them to connect to either networks.
When a VM running in this machine with a virtual interface in the Internet bridge, it can reach internet correctly, but with a source IP address that does not need SNAT'ing and is not SNAT'ed.
When another VM with a virtual interface on one of the VLAN interface/bridge, then it can reach other machines in the corresponding VLAN. Also, any machine in VLAN segments manage to reach internet using the S4810 as default gateway with no problem, including VM so long they do not run on the Internet gateway/Proxmox Hypervisor, but on any other Proxmox hypervisor machine. However, when a VM running on the Internet gateway/Proxmox Hypervisor wants to reach Internet via one of the VLANs, it fails to do so. Just like other machines that work as epected, the VM is configured to use the S4810 as default gateway. The S4810 redirects to the Internet gateway/Proxmox hypervisor any of the packets destined to Internet that it receives from it, and that gateway should forward the packet with masquerading.. except in this precise scenario, masquerading does not apply
I can see packets going to the S4810, I can see the S4810 sending back the packet to the Internet gateway, I can see the packet twice with tshark on the Internet gateway (once with ttl 64, the second time with ttl 62, i.e., after the second routing is performed) but nftables's nat postrouting table (priority srcnat) appears to catch it only once, with ttl 64, i.e., before it is sent anywhere, and before masquerading needs applying. When the packet is back and masquerading needs to be applied, it seems that nftables does not see it at all, as asserted with meta nftrace set 1 rule at the top of the nat postrouting table, and the corresponding nft monitor trace command. As a result, masquerading is not applied at all and the outside node receiving the packet receives it with the source address not SNAT'ed and it cannot send a reply.
Is there such a feature in nftables that it would accept to see a given packet only once? If so, how can I deactivate it so I can apply masquerade at the right moment? Or is it something else entirely that happens? I would be happy to provide you with any log or capture you need to help me troubleshoot.

It is a feature specifically in the Netfilter nat hook1, of both iptables and nftables.
Linux NAT is stateful, as it has the requirements that e.g. every packet belonging to the same flow would be SNATed to the same source address:port (even if conditions that would influence the port choice happen to change mid-flow), and of course that reply packets would be correctly un-NATed.
Because of that, NAT state is remembered per conntrack state (the same conntrack which tracks "new, related, established" states for your filter rules). Only the first packet of a flow goes through the nat rules; after snat/dnat/masquerade has – or hasn't – been applied to the first packet, the NAT decisions are stored in conntrack and automatically applied to all subsequent packets matching that conntrack state, meaning that those packets no longer go through the nat hooks1 so that they will not get double-NATed.
(You can see the states in conntrack -L.)
If you have a particularly weird setup where the same packets go through the same router twice (in the same network namespace), my first thought is that they shouldn't be getting routed by the same router twice. (I'm guessing you might have "apply iptables rules to bridged packets" enabled?)
It should be possible to work around this by explicitly marking those packets as "untracked" in a sufficiently-early chain when they go through your ruleset the first time, so that they won't touch conntrack (or NAT) until they come back for their second trip.
table inet foo {
    chain prerouting {
        type filter hook prerouting priority -300;
        # This should match the first group of packets but not the second
        iifname foo oifname bar notrack
    }
}

Alternatively, try the (relatively new) conntrack zone feature – ct zone set XXX (in the same chain where you'd use notrack) appears to allow marking the packets as belonging to distinct flows, which would be a much nicer method than notrack if it works.
Alternatively, split the two configurations into different network namespaces.

1 The table name in nftables is irrelevant – only the per-chain type nat hook ... setting decides when packets go through the chain.

Both notrack and ct zone set 150 work just fine. I could not use oifname to filter though, since in the prerouting hook, this is not yet known. nft traces showed it and a rule using oifname was unable to match the "first" packet. As you pointed out, there is something icky about having a packet leaving a physical machine to a router to be immediately sent back to the same physical machine. I would prefer the output packet to be output via the right interface right away, but I could not find a way to rewrite the output interface in nftables. Any more clue?

Can't really suggest anything without understanding why your current network is set up this way (it's even unclear whether the initial packets get routed or only bridged, and if it's the latter then why nftables looks at bridge traffic at all – maybe some of it is Proxmox's specifics). Either way it warrants a whole separate thread, and probably a network diagram.

Makes sense. Might create a question for this topic. Thanks a lot for your help!
